# Can't install ros-lunar on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install `ros-lunar` on Ubuntu 16.10 (I already tried to install it also on 17.10 with no success)

i always get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-lunar-desktop : Depends: ros-lunar-common-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-lunar-geometry-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-lunar-robot but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-lunar-ros-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-lunar-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-lunar-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already tried to setup my sources.list as explained in the ros-lunar installation guide.
I had the same issue on Ubuntu 17.10.

When I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get errors like these ones:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I install ros-lunar?
Can you help me, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285226/can%27t-install-ros-lunar-on-ubuntu-16.10/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
Just an observation, but Lunar is not supported on `17.10`, see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019).

And note also that `16.10` is EOL: [notice](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/07/20/ubuntu-16-10-yakkety-yak-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2017/).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
Please show us the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` on your machine?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-13**:
I had the same problem on Ubuntu 17.04.
Anyway, I'm using UBUNTU 16.10, not Ubuntu 17.10.

This is the output on my machine 16.10.

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu yakkety main
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
See  [Ubuntu 16.10 Update problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383446) for why your `apt-get update` isn't working. Ubuntu Yakkety is end-of-life (ie: not supported any more by Canonical). This could be why the ROS pkgs aren't installing (as required pkgs can't be found).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:\

> I had the same problem on Ubuntu 17.04. Anyway, I'm using UBUNTU 16.10, not Ubuntu 17.10.

I'm not saying you're running `17.10` now, just trying to provide an explanation for why you can't install Lunar on `17.10`, which you stated you were trying before.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-13**:
So i need to downgrade to 16.04 in order to run ROS Lunar?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
The only supported (by Canonical) Ubuntu release that supports ROS Lunar would be `16.04` (or `Xenial`), yes. If you require a newer version of Ubuntu (because of hw support fi), then installing `18.04` and ROS Melodic would perhaps be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An alternative would be to update your `apt` sources to point to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. That would allow you to download the latest version of all Yakkety packages, which *might* make the latest version of ROS Lunar on Yakkety installable (provided that is the problem).

No guarantees though.

And you would be running an OS that does not get any (security) updates any more, neither any ROS updates. That might not be a good idea.

But note that I wrote: "this *could be* why the ROS pkgs aren't installing". I can't be sure it is the cause.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-13**:
As you suggested, I made my apt to point to old-releases and now I'm successfully installing ros-lunar-desktop-full with apt-get.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
As long as you're aware you're now running an unsupported OS -- and will not receive any ROS updates either any more.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-13**:
Yes, I'm on a virtual machine, I just need Lunar since I have to compile a ROS Node with catkin_make, then I will delete it. I usually use Indigo con Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately, I need to compile the node to make it work on Lunar.